# 2.80, depsgraph, how to iterate over instances invisible in viewport

Tags: python, add-on

To my understanding, suggested method of iterating over instances in 2.80 looks like this

```py
depsgraph = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
for ob_inst in depsgraph.object_instances:
    # smth
```

Unfortunately this method omits objects invisible in viewport (eg. hide_viewport property). How do I iterate over all renderable objects and instances?